# What kind of signal has laplace transform?

Tags: signals, system

I don't understand why the following statement is true:

It is possible for a signal x(t) to have a Laplace transform, but not a Fourier transform.

In addition, what's the condition for a signal to have a Laplace transform?

Comment: laplace transform as i know exist  for function that are exponential order,as fourier transform it should satisfy Dirichlet's conditions

Answer (score 1):

laplace transform as i know exist for function that are exponential order,as fourier transform it should satisfy Dirichlet's conditions,please check following link

http://www.efunda.com/math/laplace_transform/

related to fourier transform

http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/mdft/Existence_Fourier_Transform.html

Comment: Thanks for the information! From the link you provided, I found out Laplace Transform is a generalization of Fourier Transform. Signal like u(t) doesn't have a Laplace Transform but has Laplace Transform.